# Why does LLVM-MCA measure an execution stall?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-architecture, llvm-mca

Consider the following instructions from the LLVM MCA [documentation](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-mca.html)

```
vmulps      %xmm0, %xmm1, %xmm2
vhaddps     %xmm2, %xmm2, %xmm3
vhaddps     %xmm3, %xmm3, %xmm4
```

The docs contain fascinating discussion about the state transition of the instructions in a simulated loop of 3 iterations. According to the docs, the state transition is:

```
[0,0]     DeeER.    .    .   vmulps   %xmm0, %xmm1, %xmm2
[0,1]     D==eeeER  .    .   vhaddps  %xmm2, %xmm2, %xmm3
[0,2]     .D====eeeER    .   vhaddps  %xmm3, %xmm3, %xmm4
[1,0]     .DeeE-----R    .   vmulps   %xmm0, %xmm1, %xmm2
[1,1]     . D=eeeE---R   .   vhaddps  %xmm2, %xmm2, %xmm3
[1,2]     . D====eeeER   .   vhaddps  %xmm3, %xmm3, %xmm4
[2,0]     .  DeeE-----R  .   vmulps   %xmm0, %xmm1, %xmm2
[2,1]     .  D====eeeER  .   vhaddps  %xmm2, %xmm2, %xmm3
[2,2]     .   D======eeeER   vhaddps  %xmm3, %xmm3, %xmm4
```

`D` is instruction dispatch, `e` refers to an ongoing execution, `E` to its termination, and `R` to retiring. Furthermore, `=` means the instruction has been dispatched but is waiting to be executed, while `-` means the instruction waits to be retired.

Considering the sequence above, what prevents the first `vhaddps` instruction from being executed in the second cycle?

I cannot see a dependency between the prior instructions. Furthermore, the docs also highlight that the multiplication uses the `JFPM` and `JFPU1` execution units, but the addition uses other resources, namely `JFPA` and `JFPU0`. Shouldn't the addition execute earlier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vhaddps` is 3 uops: 2 shuffles and a vertical add.  The shuffle uops can only run on port 5 so there's a resource conflict.  This is why `vhaddps` has one per 2-cycle throughput.

(That's on Intel.  AMD Zen 2 and later decode it as 4 uops for the XMM version, 3 for the YMM version, strangely.  https://uops.info/).

This is why it's so bad for horizontally summing one register, only useful like here with two different inputs.

---

Also, terminology nitpick: LLVM-MCA doesn't "measure" anything, it simulates.  At best it's a loose prediction for what real hardware will do.  [uiCA](https://uica.uops.info/) tends to be closer to modeling the parts of the pipeline that matter for CPUs it supports (Intel Sandybridge-family up to Ice Lake / Rocket Lake).   Andreas Abel published a paper about it.  https://www.uops.info/uiCA.html